# Unable to configure gwt designer

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-designer

I have set up my GXT project and able to run it.
I have also installed GWT designer plug in.
But When I go in design view I get an error saying GXT needs some gxt-.css files.
I have followed all the instructions and have copied resources folder in my war directory
I am using GWT 2.5 and GXT 2.2.5
I have attached screenschot of my error.

Thanks.[image: Thats the error I am getting]

Comment: It is not clear what steps you have taken to use GXT 2.2.5 with GWT 2.5. You need to use a intermediate jar gxt-2.x.x-gwt22.jar .http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?229447-GXT-2.2.5-future-support-and-GWT-2.5.x-compatibility

Comment: Yes I have used that jar. I just renamed it to gxt.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue  is reported and fixed in GWT Designer http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6093

Check your GWT Designer plugin version or Eclipse version. It might be a regression issue from GWT team otherwise.

Comment: I added a public folder in d same package as module file and copied the resources folder in the public folder